# Calculating Non-Integer Exponent

Tags: algorithms, problem-solving

I just wanted to directly calculate the value of the number $2^{3.1}$ as I was wondering how a computer would do it. I've done some higher mathematics, but I'm very unsure of what I would do to solve this algorithmically, **without a simple trial and error**.

I noted that

$$ 2^{3.1} = 2^{3} \times 2^{0.1} $$

So I've simplified the problem to an "integer part" (which is easy enough) :  $2^3 = 2\times 2\times 2$, but I'm still very confused about the "decimal part". I also know that :

$$ 2^{0.1} = e^{0.1\log{2}} $$

But that still presents a similar problem, because you'd need to calculate another non-integer exponent for the natural exponential. As far as I can see, the only way to do this is to let:

$$2^{0.1}=a $$

And then trial and error with some brute force approach (adjusting my guess for a as I go). Even Newton's method didn't seem to give me anything meaningful. Does anybody have any idea how we could calculate this with some working algorithm?

Comment: And by a simple trial and error, I mean: how would I solve this without just using a calculator to refine to more and more decimal places.

Comment: In short, you'll have to use a calculator for the general case--computing numeric results for $\log x$ involves either infinite series or numeric integration.  (By general case, I mean that there will be exceptions, like $4^{3.5} = 8$ is easy to do without a calculator, but you can't do that in general).

Comment: $2^{0.1} = e^{0.1\log 2}$ - you got the $2$ and $0.1$ backwards.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I did get that backwards. That was a mistake I'm afraid :( However, I'm thinking of it from a more algorithmic standpoint. How does a calculator actually calculate a logarithm?

Comment: $2^{0.1}$ is just $2^{\frac{1}{10}}$, or $\sqrt[10] 2$. $\sqrt[10] 2 = n~where~n^{10}=2$, thus $f(n) = n^{10} - 2$, $f'(n) = 10n^9$ and $g(n) = n - \frac{f(n)}{f'(n)}$, thus $2^{3.1} = 2^3 * 2^{0.1} \approx 8 * g^{10}(1) \approx 8 * 1.071773462536293 \approx 8.574187700290345$, which I calculated with a function `double root(int exp, double x)` which I wrote in C with the added restriction of no math library (`-lm`). Yes, very doable with a computer. Also, $2^{3.1} = 2^{\frac{31}{10}} = \sqrt[10]{2^{31}} = $ `root(10, pow(2, 31))`

Comment: Update: [I wrote an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2995982/272911)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with:

$$2^{3.1} = 2^3 2^{0.1} = 2^3 e^{0.1 \log{2}}$$

Now use a Taylor expansion, so that the above is approximately

$$2^3  \left [1+0.1 \log{2} + \frac{1}{2!} (0.1 \log{2})^2 + \frac{1}{3!} (0.1 \log{2})^3+\cdots + \frac{1}{n!} (0.1 \log{2})^n\right ] $$

wheer $n$ depends on the tolerance you require.  In this case, if this error tolerance is $\epsilon$, then we want

$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} (0.1 \log{2})^{n+1} \lt \epsilon$$

For example, if $\epsilon=5 \cdot 10^{-7}$, then $n=4$.

Comment: Tis a very good idea. That was actually how I solved this :) I just wrote a Small java program to do it using nothing but basic arithmetic. I'd be happy to post it if any body is interested

Comment: excellent answer, and for $n=10$ this is perfectly accurate, i.e if $ϵ=0$ then $n=10$

Answer (score 4):

> I just wanted to directly calculate the value of the number $2^{3.1}$ **as I was wondering how a computer would do it**

(emphasis mine)

What follows is quite possibly one of the most detailed answers I've ever written on this network. I believe this thoroughly answers your question about "how a computer would do it", so it warrants a read.

This answer is broken into four main sections, titled:

1. **Figuring out the problem domain** - where I show how to work out the problem by hand
2. **Getting to $8\sqrt[10]2$ programmatically** - where I show how to get a computer to work out the problem
3. **Implementing root(exp, x)** - describing how to implement nth root approximations
4. **An actual implementation** - a full C implementation culminating in the calculation of $2^{3.1}$, among other things.

This isn't StackOverflow, so I'll try to respect that and refrain from going into too much technical detail. That said, any non-pseudocode example code I include will be in C, since C has a relatively low level of abstraction and thus an algorithm implemented in C is more *concrete*, and thus more easily ported to other languages.

### Figuring out the problem domain

That said, the way I would approach this is by first representing the exponent as a fraction, factoring and simplifying that, and solving the simplified radical.

$
2^{3.1} =\\
2^{\frac{31}{10}} =\\
\sqrt[10]{2^{31}} =\\
\sqrt[10] {2^{10} * 2^{10} * 2^{10} * 2^1} =\\
2 * 2 * 2 * \sqrt[10] 2 =\\
8\sqrt[10] 2
$

Now we have something that can be represented in a program:

```
8 * root(10, 2)
```

### Getting to $8\sqrt[10]2$ programmatically

Of course, going from `pow(2, 3.1)` to `8 * root(10, 2)` with a machine that only understands how to perform addition and multiplication isn't exactly trivial, so you would probably want to separate the integer and decimal components; i.e. what you did.

```
#define GET_INT(n) \
    ( (double)((int)(n)) )

#define GET_DEC(n) \
    ( (n) - GET_INT(n) )

#define IS_INT(n) \
    ( GET_INT(n) == (n) )
```

Thus, $2^{3.1} =~...$

```
pow(a, b):
  IS_INT(b):
    pow(a, b)
  otherwise:
    bi = GET_INT(b)
    bf = GET_DEC(b)
    pow(a, bi) * root( get_denom(bf), pow(a, get_numer(bf)) )

pow(2, 3.0):
  IS_INT(3.0)
    8

pow(2, 3.2):
  otherwise
    bi = 3.0
    bf = 0.2
    pow(2, 3.0) * root(10, pow(2, 2))
```

where `get_numer` and `get_denom` are functions that take e.g. `0.2` and return `2` and `10`, respectively. I'm not sure how to implement these two functions, but I know it's doable. For example, you might multiply `bf` by 10 until `IS_INT(bf)` is true, and then return `bf` for the numerator and $10^{the~number~of~times~you~multiplied~bf~by~10}$ for the denominator, but *does this satisfactorily cover the problem domain and perform without unexpected floating-point related bugs, rounding errors or over/underflow*? I cannot answer that. All I can say is that the approach should work **in theory** for a decent range of values. The implementation of our naive approach looks like this:

```
double *dec_to_frac(double x){
    double magnitude = 1;
    static double ret[2];

    while(IS_INT(x) == 0){
        x *= 10;
        magnitude *= 10;
    }

    ret[0] = x;
    ret[1] = magnitude;
    return ret;
}

double get_numer(double x){
    double *frac = dec_to_frac(x);
    return frac[0];
}

double get_denom(double x){
    double *frac = dec_to_frac(x);
    return frac[1];
}
```

That said, we have now established an algorithm for calculating $a^b$ for float-compatible values > 0.

So now, for an input of $2^{3.1}$, you have the following C expression:

```
pow(a, bi) * root(get_denom(bf), pow(a, get_numer(bf)))
```

where `a = 2.0, bf = 0.1, bi = 3.0`

We have everything we need to calculate a good approximation, except for one function, `root`, which I will now go over.

### Implementing root(exp, x)

First, we need to establish based on an example, so we'll start with cube roots.

Put simply, the goal is to turn the problem into an equation, turn the equation into a function $f(n)$, find the derivative of that function $f'(n)$, and then repeatedly calculate $n - \frac{f(n)}{f'(n)}$ where $n$ is the seed value or "guess". This will give you an approximation.

$
\sqrt[3]x = n~where~n^3 = x\\
n^3 = x\\
n^3 - x = 0\\
f(n) = n^3 - x\\
f'(n) = 3n^2\\
g(n) = n - \frac{f(n)}{f'(n)}\\
\sqrt[3]x \approx g^P(Q)~where~P~is~the~desired~precision~and~Q~is~the~initial~guess
$

Generalizing this, we get

$
\sqrt[I]x = n~where~n^I = x\\
n^I = x\\
n^I - x = 0\\
f(n) = n^I - x\\
f'(n) = In^{I - 1}\\
g(n) = n - \frac{f(n)}{f'(n)}\\
\sqrt[I]x \approx g^P(Q)
$

Which I believe is properly expressed as...

$
\sqrt[I]x \approx g^P(Q) ~where...\\
g(n) = n - \frac{f(n)}{f'(n)}\\
f(n) = n^I - x\\
f'(n) = In^{I - 1}\\
$

Now, we can implement

```
#define PRECISION 10
#define MAX(a, b) ( (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b) )

double root(int exp, double x){
    double guess = MAX(1.0, x / exp);

    for(int i = 0; i < PRECISION; ++i)
        guess -= (pow(guess, (double)exp) - x) / ( exp * pow(guess, (double)(exp - 1)) );

    return guess;
}
```

Putting all of that together into a specialized `pow(double, double)` function, with an input of `(2.0, 3.1)`, you should get an output of roughly `8.574187700290345`.

### An actual implementation

What follows is my implementation, which I make no guarantees about being robust. I've also added some extra details to account for some complicated idiosyncrasies regarding how the computer represents floats.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

#define PRECISION 20

#define MAX(a, b) \
    ( (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b) )

#define MIN(a, b) \
    ( (a) < (b) ? (a) : (b) )

#define GET_INT(n) \
    ( (double)((int)(n)) )

#define GET_DEC(n) \
    ( (n) - GET_INT(n) )

#define IS_INT(n) \
    ( MAX((n), GET_INT(n)) - MIN((n), GET_INT(n)) <= FLT_EPSILON )

int *dec_to_frac(double);
int get_numer(double);
int get_denom(double);
double fpow(double, double);
double ipow(double, int);
double root(int exp, double x);

int *
dec_to_frac(double x)
{
    int magnitude = 1;
    static int ret[2];

    while(IS_INT(x) == 0){
        x *= 10;
        magnitude *= 10;
    }

    ret[0] = (int)x;
    ret[1] = magnitude;
    return ret;
}

int
get_numer(double x)
{
    return (dec_to_frac(x))[0];
}

int
get_denom(double x)
{
    return (dec_to_frac(x))[1];
}

double
fpow(double a, double b)
{
    double bi;
    double bf;

    if(IS_INT(b))
        return ipow(a, (int)b);

    bi = GET_INT(b);
    bf = GET_DEC(b);

    return ipow(a, (int)bi) * root( get_denom(bf), ipow(a, get_numer(bf)) );
}

double
ipow(double a, int b)
{
    double total = 1.0;

    while(b--)
        total *= a;

    return total;
}

double
root(int exp, double x)
{
    double guess = MAX(1.0, x / exp);

    for(int i = 0; i < PRECISION; i++)
        guess -= (ipow(guess, exp) - x) / ( exp * ipow(guess, exp - 1) );

    return guess;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("pow(2, 3) = %.1f\n", fpow(2.0, 3.0));
    printf("pow(2, 3.1) = %.15f\n", fpow(2.0, 3.1));
    printf("root(2, 2) = %.15lf\n", root(2, 2.0));
    printf("root(3, 3) = %.15lf\n", root(3, 3.0));
    printf("root(2, 9) = %.15lf\n", root(2, 9.0));
    printf("root(4, 81) = %.15lf\n", root(4, 81.0));

    return 0;
}
```

Running this program generates the following output:

```
pow(2, 3) = 8.0
pow(2, 3.1) = 8.574187700290345
root(2, 2) = 1.414213562373095
root(3, 3) = 1.442249570307408
root(2, 9) = 3.000000000000000
root(4, 81) = 3.000000000000000
```

Comment: In practice, a direct translation of what's described (before the full implementation at the end) will enter an infinite loop, because while `0.1 * 10 == 1.0`, `GET_DEC(3.1)` actually yields `0.10000000000000008881784197001252323...` instead of vanilla `0.1`. Hence why the `FLT_EPSILON` comparison was added to `IS_INT(n)`. Epsilon is the smallest representable floating point value.

Answer (score 3):

To answer a question that me from the past had :P
The basic idea is that you could actually calculate both of these directly.

$$ 2^{3.1} = e^{2 \log\left( 3.1 \right)} $$

So really the procedure is simple:

1. Take the natural log of 3.1
2. Multiply by the base (2)
3. Use the result as the argument to $\exp(x) $ or $e^x$

So this problem is really reduced to, how do calculators calculate logarithms and exponentials? The answer to that isn't so hard. I'm not giving the fastest methods by any means, there are some series that converge to these values much more quickly than the ones I've suggested, but this should get anybody who sees this in the future on track pretty quickly :).

## Calculating the Log

To calculate the logarithm, a numerical method like the trapezoidal rule or Simpsons rule would be sufficient; because:

$$ \log (x) = \int_1^x { 1 \over t } dt $$

## Calculating the Exponential

Here we could just use the direct limit definition:

$$ \exp (x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+{x \over n }\right)^n $$

Where n is just some large integer (so you just multiply directly), or you could again, approximate $e^x $ with a taylor series, which should converge to the actual answer a little more quickly, since:

$$ \exp (x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( 1 + x + {x^2 \over 2!} + {x^3 \over 3!} + ... + {x^n \over n!} \right) $$

However, most calculators store some of these values in a LUT (look up table), since they will be (at least partially) pre-calculated with more accuracy than you are likely to need. This allows modern computers to find the exponential and logarithm of a function very quickly [although X86 - which is the instruction set used by most common computers today actually calculates $2^x$ and $log_2 (x)$, because its easy to calculate them in binary (base 2)].

Comment: Just a small note: $2^{3.1} \approx 8.574 \neq e^{2 \log\left( 3.1 \right)} = 9.61$, but rather the other way around in the exponent $2^{3.1} = e^{3.1 \log\left( 2 \right)} \approx 8.574$

Comment: Whoops, total misstep there. Thanks for that :D

Comment: Also, your limit definition of $ \text{exp}\left( x \right) $ is incorrect. It should be $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( 1+\frac {x}{n} \right) ^n $$

Comment: Oh yep, fixed. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Trial and error is how a finance calculator will solve for interest in a present value calculation.

If a log function is solved quickly, it's possible to be a lookup table, or trial/error with a fast processor.

Try creating a spreadsheet, where ten consecutive cells each represent a single digit, from the whole number to nine beyond the decimal. If a^10=2 it would stand to reason to start with 1.0xxxx and I'd say that on a bet you can guess the next digit in a couple seconds.

You started by not wanting trial and error, but then gave into it toward the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

3.1 = 31/10

$2^{3.1}$ = 10th root of $2^{31}$ or $2^{31/10}$.

Adapted Newton's approximation to find the 10th root of a number $x$, it goes as follows.

Start off with some initial guess $y$ for the answer.

1. $y$ is your current guess (say, 8)
2. A better estimate is $$y - \frac{y^{10} - x}{10 y^9}$$ (which, in this case, gives 8.8)
3. Repeat until it is accurate enough.

Comment: This is exactly how I'd do it - I'd have added a [link or an explanation for your formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) if I showed somebody how, though.