# Calculating non-integer exponents

Tags: exponentiation

I'm trying to create a fully functioning calculator in Ruby and have been stuck for quite some time on calculating non-integer exponents, e.g. $3^{2.4}$. I would like to be able to support decimal powers without using any libraries. Knowing how to work out a given log by hand would also be useful as I would like to add log support in eventually. I have plans to look into Taylor expansion as suggested by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462443/calculating-non-integer-exponent) but haven't really had time. I'm open to any and all suggestions.

---

UPDATE: I figured it out. To calculate $3^{2.4}$, for example, you would first convert it to a decimal leaving $3^{(\frac{24}{10})}$. Optionally, you would then reduce it leaving $3^{(\frac{12}{5})}$. From here, you take the base to the power of the numerator, $3^{12}$, and take it to the root of the denominator finally giving you $\sqrt[5]{3^{12}}$ which can be calculated with the [Nth Root Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm), and a list of this algorithm being implemented in various programming languages can be found [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Nth_root).

Comment: This seems to be more of a programming question than a math question.

Comment: I understand why you would say that, but I would like someone to explain the steps to solve it. I'll worry about putting it into code later.

Answer (score 1):

Iterative methods for computing logarithms are notoriously slow. Check out the following recent paper: [Fast log algorithm](https://www.siam.org/students/siuro/vol7/S01325.pdf)